# getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined"

Tags: json

i have the following code

```
function loadAQI(cityCoords){
        var latlng = cityCoords.coords.latitude +"&lon="+ cityCoords.coords.longitude;
```

i am trying to make my API more dynamic with latitudes and longitudes but i keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined

$(document).ready(function(){
        loadAQI();
        $("a.city").bind("click",function(){
            loadCity($(this).html());
        });
```

this is where i call the loadAQI function
            });

Comment: Something is causing the value being passed into `loadAQI` to be `undefined`. If you give the code that involves the call to that function as well, maybe we can help

Comment: i am calling the the function in the ready     $(document).ready(function(){
   loadAQI();
   $("a.city").bind("click",function(){
    loadCity($(this).html());
   });
   });

Answer (score 0):

When your document loads with the following lifecycle hook...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadAQI();  // <---- NOOO
    $("a.city").bind("click", function() {
        loadCity($(this).html());
    }); 
});
```

You are calling `loadAQI();` without **any arguments when the function relies on one**.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined` is being thrown because you are trying to access a property of an object that is never being passed to the function.

Comment: thank you very much @m_callens i didnt see that and i have been whining about it since,